# C# findindex with multiple expressions

Tags: c#

How can I search a list for two different things?

For example, this code works perfectly fine:

```
int index = mylistofobjects.FindIndex(a => a.firstname == "Bob");
```

Is there a way to change it to something like this?

```
int index = mylistofobjects.FindIndex(a => a.firstname == "Bob", a.lastname == "Smith");
```

I'm trying to return the mylistofobjects instance that has first name Bob and lastname Smith.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

int index = mylistofobjects.FindIndex(a => a.firstname == "Bob"&& a.lastname == "Smith");

Answer (score 3):

Use && operator.

```
int index = mylistofobjects.FindIndex(a => a.firstname == "Bob" && a.lastname == "Smith");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [conditional AND operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx) `&&`:

```
int index = mylistofobjects.FindIndex(
    a => a.firstname == "Bob" && a.lastname == "Smith");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `&&` (logic and) to combine multiple conditionals

```
int index = mylistofobjects.FindIndex(a => a.firstname == "Bob" && a.lastname == "Smith")
```